# Pulling Burndown Charts From Visual Studio Online API

Tags: api, charts, get, azure-devops, sprint

I'm trying to pull burndown charts for sprints from VSO to display alongside other project data. I'd assume that there is no way to pull an actual image or URL to the burndown, although that would be ideal. If this is not possible, is there some way to pull values that I could use to re-create a chart? I've been digging through the API for a few days with no luck so far.

So basically, I need to pull SOMETHING from VSO that will allow me to display the burndown for the current sprint of a project, in some way.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty late answer, but it is possible as of now to get the image of burndown chart directly from Azure DevOps using Chartimages - Get Iteration Chart Image API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/iterations/{iterationId}/chartimages/{name}?width={width}&height={height}&showDetails={showDetails}&title={title}&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

For burndown chart, `{name}` = `Burndown`.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/chartimages/get%20iteration%20chart%20image?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 1):

The data for the burn down is calculated by using a standard query with an 'as of' Param.

The as of param is only available in the API and returns the results as it would have on that date. If you count the work within the scope that you want for each day you will have the data.

I would recommend caching the results.

Comment: So yes, you can draw your own burndown.  You just need to collate the hours remaining for each day (using 'as of') for your sprint?

Comment: if you are looking to generate a quick burndown chart image you can use this free service: https://documentation.image-charts.com/gallery/